# Failing to use sumproduct on date ranges with multiple conditions [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, sumproduct

From replacement data table (below on the image), I am trying to incorporate the solbox product replace in time series data format(above on the image). I need to extract out the number of consumers per day from the information.

What I need to find out:

1. On a specific date, which number of solbox product was active
2. On a specific date, which number of solbox product (which was a consumer) was active

I have used this line of code in excel but cannot implement this on python properly.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Record_Solbox_Replacement!$O$2:$O$1367 = "consumer") * (A475>=Record_Solbox_Replacement!$L$2:$L$1367)*(A475<Record_Solbox_Replacement!$M$2:$M$1367))
```

[image]

I tried in python -

```
timebase_df['date']  = pd.date_range(start = replace_table_df['solbox_started'].min(), end = replace_table_df['solbox_started'].max(), freq = frequency)
timebase_df['date_unix'] = timebase_df['date'].astype(np.int64) // 10**9
timebase_df['no_of_solboxes'] = ((timebase_df['date_unix']>=replace_table_df['started'].to_numpy()) & (timebase_df['date_unix'] < replace_table_df['ended'].to_numpy() & replace_table_df['customer_type'] == 'customer']))
```

ERROR:

```
~\Anaconda3\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    232         #  The ambiguous case is object-dtype.  See GH#27803
    233         if len(lvalues) != len(rvalues):
--> 234             raise ValueError("Lengths must match to compare")
    235 
    236     if should_extension_dispatch(lvalues, rvalues):

ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

Can someone help me please? I can explain in comment section if I have missed something.